# geopands sjoin_nearest returns only the nearest result

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I used the new function sjoin_nearest in geopands 0.10. According to the official document, "Results will include multiple output records for a single input record where there are multiple equidistant nearest or intersected neighbors". I only got one return which is the nearest result, here is my code

```
street_geo.crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
buf = mcd_street_geo.copy()
buf=buf.to_crs({'init':'epsg:3857'})
locationgeo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(location,geometry = 'geometry')
locationgeo.crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}
locationgeo=locationgeo.to_crs(3857)
merge_test=buf.sjoin_nearest(locationgeo,max_distance=200,distance_col='distance')
```

Comment: Does your data contain "multiple equidistant nearest or intersected neighbors"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you're doing from your code, but I don't think anything is going wrong. Have you checked whether there actually are multiple **equidistant** nearest or intersected neighbors? If there is a single nearest neighbor, or the geometry intersects with only one other geometry, sjoin_nearest() will only return that neighbor.